# Another way to say "Replace your currently selected item"?

Tags: usability, buttons, user-expectation

I'm building a part to our e-commerce store, it's essentially a "kit builder" for building several products in to one big kit, giving the user a discount.

The use can only select one item per category. If they decide they no longer want that item, and want to replace it with another item in that category, there's not way to tell them that the original item has been removed. Our buttons say "Add to Kit" and "Remove from Kit" on the currently selected item. So, if they hit "Add to kit" on another item in that category, it will remove the other item.

We essentially need another way to say "Replace the currently selected item in this category with this new item", but we need to say it in about 3 words. Something like "Replace current product", but more intuitive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a phrase to use here, I'd go with:

> replace [category name]

But honestly it sounds to me like the issue here is how the buttons work, not what you've labelled them with.

Having an "add to kit" button that can be repeatedly clicked is signalling to the user that they can keep using it without affecting the results of previous clicks.

The cleanest solution would be to change the way the interaction works so that they can only select one thing at a time, and selecting a new thing visibly deselects the old thing.

Here are a couple of ways of doing this off the top of my head:

- Radio buttons are the standard way to show this interaction
- You could visibly show the old selection, and put a button next to it that says "replace".
- You could show a manifest page after the first button click, showing all the available categories in the kit as open slots, with one of the slots filled by their first selection. Then show a button underneath to change the contents of a slot, and a second button to put a new item into an open slot.